# where do I get ndiswrapper v1.57?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, software-center

I am trying to get my wireless adapter to work.  According to some places, I need v 1.57 of ndiswrapper.  There are instructions on how to compile it after making changes to the source, but I am not comfortable doing what is asked.  I don't know enough to know weather what I do works or screws up my system.

Where can I get a compiled 32 bit version of ndiswrapper for Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: ... only use ndiswrapper as a last resort - why dont you create a question with details of your wireless card.  Maybe we can help getting it to work with the inbuilt kernel...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the latest `ndiswrapper` from [the official website on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page) (at the time of writing version 1.57 is the latest stable release). Ubuntu 11.10 has `ndiswrapper-common` version 1.56, Ubuntu 12.04 offers version 1.57. Honestly, although having the latest release of any software is ideal, I highly doubt that using ndiswrapper 1.57 over 1.56 will really make a big difference with your wireless adapter. I recommend first trying with the `ndiswrapper-common` package available in the repositories, if that doesn't work, then grab the latest stable release from the Sourceforge website and install it from source. Alternatively, you may be able to download the deb packages (your 32-bit compiled binaries) in launchpad for Ubuntu 12.04, but this could break your system and is not encouraged.

Ndiswrapper is tricky enough as it is for those configuring their wireless adapter in Ubuntu for the first time, it's best not to complicate things and use the version available in the repositories if that version can suffice.